# Error in displaying data with TextView.setText: Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-resources

I am getting this exception:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
```

The exception stack trace points to this line in the adapter class:

```java
holder.no_of_sems.setText(cgpa.getNo_of_sems());
```

This is my adapter class:

```java
public class adapter_cgpa extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_cgpa.Viewholder> {
    ArrayList<POJO> cgpaArrayList;

    public adapter_cgpa(ArrayList<POJO> cgpaArrayList) {
        this.cgpaArrayList = cgpaArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public adapter_cgpa.Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View listitem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_cgpa, parent, false);
        return new Viewholder(listitem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull adapter_cgpa.Viewholder holder, int position) {
        POJO cgpa= cgpaArrayList.get(position);
        holder.no_of_sems.setText(cgpa.getNo_of_sems());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cgpaArrayList.size();
    }

    public class Viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView cname, no_of_sems, cgpa, percentage,schemec;
        ImageButton btndelete2;

        public Viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            no_of_sems=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.no_of_sem);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my POJO class:

```java
public class POJO {
    int no_of_sems;

    public void setNo_of_sems(int no_of_sems) {
        this.no_of_sems = no_of_sems;
    }

    public int getNo_of_sems() {
        return no_of_sems;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accidentally calling [the version of `TextView.setText` that takes an `int` resource ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)).

You should explicitly convert it to a `String`:

```java
holder.no_of_sems.setText(Integer.toString(cgpa.getNo_of_sems()));
```